# Rad studio or android studio

Tags: android, window, rad

I'm going to learn a to develop android apps ( I'm web developer right now ) but I'm confused about the Ide which I should start with.
I know android studio is suggested IDE for android development by google. On the other hand, the embarcadero claims that by their IDE you can develop your app for android, IOS, Win10, and mac which sounds really tempting. can any one clarify the pros and cons of each IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try both of them. A list of things like: better refactor tools, elegant UI, performance, and etc needed to be consider to choose which to use. It was USELESS if you don't download and try them, they sure have different pros and cons. BTW I'll recommend Android Studio since I used it from start and have not encounters any big trouble yet, it get frequent updates too. And recently I've heard about [Appcelerator Studio](http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/appcelerator-studio/) which seem like a great IDE tool, but it was not free.

Comment: any more recommendation?

Comment: Eclipse, and more check this link http://tekeye.biz/2014/list-of-android-app-development-ides, but if you are develope using mainly JAVA, Android studio is what best suite you

Answer (score 1):

I use Delphi for application development mainly because my application run on windows, android and ios with same code. If your aim is to target multiple platforms without additional work Delphi is a good choice. Another advantage of using Delphi is it is a Rapid Application Developmet tool that means less time developing.

Answer (score -2):

You can look into the prospect of using IBM Mobile First platform for developing native as well hybrid apps. End to end tutorials could be found here https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/all-tutorials/

Comment: the link is broken (404)

Comment: @dpant This is the new link https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/all-tutorials/

Comment: @dpant I couldn't understand the downvote. The answer was provided in Sept 15. Back then the link was valid. You expect me to keep checking all my answers to see if the links still work or not?